# how to get "this" content when using javascript "Object Proxy"

Tags: javascript, node.js

there's a function Actor.getIndexVar(index) , i want code like  Actor.indexVar[i] to get the indexed data . so i find the Proxy object. but can't get this content in "Proxy.get". i write a test sample below.

```
let Actor = function () {}

Actor.prototype = {
    getIndexVar: function (index) {
        return "actor :" + index
    },

    name: function () {
        return "Actor"
    }
}

let Human = function () {
    this.getIndexVar = function (index) {
        return "Human :" + index
    }
}

Human.prototype = Actor.prototype

Actor.prototype.indexVar = new Proxy(Actor, {
    get: function (target, property, receiver) {
        //i want get `hum1` instance here.
        //i dont want create proxy object per instance.
        // because the instance was create frequently (from c++ native object bind)
        // thanks all :)
        return target.getIndexVar(property)
    }
});

let hum1 = new Human()
console.log(hum1.indexVar[1])
```